# Kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init! and previous kernels do not work

Tags: boot, kernel

I am new on using Linux. I use it for some imaging analysis. Today my ubuntu upgraded itself but at the end of the upgrade it gave error. After that the system blocked. I restarted the machine manually but a black screen opened and it gave  "karnel panic - not syncing: Attempeted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100"  error.

I googled this problem. Someone say that open advanced  options for ubuntu and select previous kernels. I tried all of them but any of them worked.

I have lots of things in my computer and I dont want to lose them. Can you help me?

Comment: The data can be easily recovered. The problem is getting the kernel to work.

Comment: First try boot repair - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @BharadwajRaju - depends on the reason for the kernel panic, i the hard drive failed, then data recovery may not be so easy

Comment: Do you dual boot with windows or do you have just linux?

Comment: Dual boot with windows

Comment: Unfortunately boot repair did not work. I could reach my files with live usb. I think I will copy them and reinstall ubuntu. Thank you for replies.